# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. (Python Request Module)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests, httprequest

## I have this function in my views.py (Django project)

```
def boardsJson(request):
    user=request.GET.get('user')
    password=request.GET.get('password')
    :
    :
    Bla Bla Bla 
    :
    :
    return HttpResponse("Login Success")
```

## I am tryingto login by this request module.

```
import requests
URL = "http://35.196.206.72:8000/boardsJson/"
PARAMS = {
    'user':'1234567890',
    'password':'kak',
    }
r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS)
print(r.text)
```

Every thing is well until I am using the GET method to login.
But if I use the POST(I Just replaced the "GET"  with  "POST" every where) method then I am getting the message something like bellow.

```
  <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>
  <p>You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.</p>
  <p>If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for âsame-originâ requests.</p>
```

So please help me to solve it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to either include the CSRF Token in the post or add the CSRF Exempt decorator to the view if you which to bypass it.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def boardsJson(request):
    user=request.GET.get('user')
    password=request.GET.get('password')
    :
    :
    Bla Bla Bla 
    :
    :
    return HttpResponse("Login Success")
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#unprotected-view-needs-the-csrf-token

Comment: Thank you for your precious attention.

I want to login using the second script (that is a boat Not a Html page).

r = requests.post(url = URL, params = PARAMS)

So what are the changes to be done in the second script specially?

Comment: If the page is a normal django form and you are trying to then log in using a bot then you will need to make two requests to the page.

Request number 1 - make a GET request to the page and extract the CSRF token. I would suggest using BeautifulSoup4 for that https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/. Then you can submit a POST request with the Username and Password as you are now along with the CSRF token you have extracted from the page.